# How can I ask a JMS server to resend the message when an exception occurs in a JMS listener defined with the @JmsListener annotation?

Tags: annotations, jms, listener, spring-boot

I have been writing a JMS listener in a Springboot application.
I used two ways:

1) Defines a a bean which is SimpleMessageListenerContainer like this:

```
    @Bean
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer getMyMessageListenerContainer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        MessageListenerAdapter messageListener = new MessageListenerAdapter(myService);
        messageListener.setDefaultListenerMethod("myMethodListener");
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setMessageListener(messageListener);
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setDestinationName("aMessageQueue");
        return container;
    }   


class MyService{
    public void myMethodListener(String argument){
        // do something...
    }
}
```

or 2) Using the simple JMSListener annotation, like this:

```
class MyService{
    @JmsListener(destination="aMessageQueue")
    public void myMethodListener(String argument) {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

I like the last approach. It is very simple and documents quite simply the code. Unfortunately I noticed that both ways behave quite differently.

If there is an exception thrown in method 1), the JMS server will resend the message to the listener. In method 2) if there is an exception thrown the server does not retry sending the message to the listener.

How can I tell the server to resend the message when an exception occurs in the listener defined using the JMSListener annotation?

Thanks for your help.

Jean

Comment: They are different, the first uses a `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` whereas the second uses a `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` which behaves differently. If you have a transaction manager (for JPA for instance) the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` should have transactional behavior and rollback on error (if it is a runtime exception!) if you don't have add a `JmsTransactionManager` to your configuration. Or completely [configure](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/annotation/JmsListener.html) the JMS environment yourself.

Comment: Thanks mdeinum for guiding into new areas. I am not using JPA for this project, no access to SQL DB. So I tried many things. The simplest solution I found for me was to load the "spring-boot-starter-jta-bitronix" and that did the trick.

Comment: If you don't need multiple transactional resources that is overkill as it will enable XA which has additional costs as opposed to local transactions. The simplest thing is to just register a `JmsTransactionManager` if all you need is transactions for JMS.

Comment: How do you do that in a Spring Boot application?

Comment: Just add it as a `@Bean`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply added to my pom.xml the following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jta-bitronix</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and my listeners now look like this:

```
class MyService{
  @JmsListener(destination="aMessageQueue")
  public void myMethodListener(String argument) {
    // do something...
  }
}
```

And they will be called again even if an exception would be thrown in my listener.